# Deploy ASP.NET Core on render.com says Not Found

Tags: asp.net-core, web-deployment, render.com

Can I deploy an ASP.NET Core app to [Render](https://render.com)?

I linked my GitHub repo and in the CLI it says `Your site is live` , but when I access the website it just says `Not found`.

Comment: You need to find a host that supports .NET Core, which they don't seem to be.

Answer (score 1):

From [Render's docs](https://render.com/docs/web-services):

> Our platform has native support for Node.js, Python, Ruby, Elixir, Go, and Rust. If these don’t work for you, we can also build and deploy anything with a Dockerfile.

So Render does not have native support for C#, F# or VBA, so .NET won't work out of the box. This can be solved by using Docker as [Render supports Docker containers](https://render.com/docs/docker).

Deploying your apps in Docker is good practice anyway, as Docker virtualises your app and runs it in an isolated environment, so if it works locally in [Docker Desktop](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/), it will work in production.

If you're new to Docker, check out [their Get Started docs](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/). If you redeploy your .NET app with the same code but Dockerized, it should work fine.